# DatePicker format

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using datepicker from jQuery. Once selected, I want it to display as 9Feb, 11. However when saving I want it to convert it to 2/9/11. How can I do that?

When re-displaying the dte, it should display 9Feb, 11 again. How can I do that?

My piece of code is as follows:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => (Model.dDay.Date))

 $("#dDay_Date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the 'altField' option to populate a hidden field in your form, just change the date field to hidden: `<input type="hidden" name="date" id="date" value=""/>`. You also set the format of the alt field with 'altFormat':

```
$("#date_display").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'd M y', 
    altField: '#date',
    altFormat: 'dd-M-yy'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden input field to the page. Using the `altField` and `altFormat` options you can send the data to you page in an alternative format.

To do this, you can create a custom editor template for the DateTime format. Add the file DateTime.cshtml to the Views/Shared/EditorTemplates folder.

You can then use a contents like this (not tested):

```
@model DateTime?
@using System.Globalization
@{
    var name = MvcHtmlString.Create(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(""));
    var id = MvcHtmlString.Create(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(""));
    var visibleID = id + "_editor";

    var value = Model ?? DateTime.Today;
    var formattedValue = value.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");

}
<input type="text" id="@(visibleID)" value="@formattedValue" />
<input type="hidden" id="@(id)" name="@(name)" value="@value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")" />
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () { $('#@(visibleID)').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'd mm y', altField='@id', altFormat='d/m/y' }); });
</script>
```

Then you only have to use the TextBoxFor, any DateTime field will have the datetimepicker activated.

Comment: Is there a simpler and cleaner way of doing the above?

Comment: You only add the DateTime.cshtml once. Then in your page you just use TextBoxFor. How clean can it get?

Comment: Ok, I didn`t understand it.  Is is a helper?